# How do I get individual clusters on 3 different levels?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Here's the dot file I have:

```
digraph G {
   rankdir=TB;
   ranksep=1;

   subgraph cluster_application {

       subgraph cluster_module_core {
         init_a -> service_a;
         init_a -> service_b;
         init_a -> service_c;
         init_a -> service_d;
       }

       subgraph cluster_module_a {
         init_d -> service_c_1;
         init_d -> service_d_1;
       }

       subgraph cluster_module_b {
         init_b -> service_a_1;
         init_b -> service_b_1;
       }

       subgraph cluster_module_db {
         init_c -> db_service;
         db_service -> db;
       }
   }

   main -> init_a;
   main -> init_b;
   main -> init_c;
   main -> init_d;

   service_a -> service_a_1;
   service_b -> service_b_1;
   service_c -> service_c_1;
   service_d -> service_d_1;

   service_a_1 -> db_service;
   service_b_1 -> db_service;
   service_c_1 -> db_service;
   service_d_1 -> db_service;
}
```

How do I get a visual that would look like this:

```
                        Main
                         |
                         |
                   +------------+
                   |    core    |
                   +------------+
                    /  /     \  \
                   /  /       \  \
          +-----------+     +-----------+
          | Module A  |     |  Module B |
          +-----------+     +-----------+
                   \  \       /  /
                    \  \     /  /
                   +-------------+
                   | Module DB   |
                   +-------------+
```

So we can clearly see that ModuleA and ModuleB act as middlewares? I tried groupping them in clusters but I still get cluster to overlap on vertical axis instead of them being clearly on different levels. I don't mind if lines cross boxes as it's not possible otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are not satisfied with how graphviz positioned nodes on the graph, you are entering an ugly world of invisible edges, constraint-falses and weights.

I've added `constraint=false` attribute for your `main -> init_c` edge and added few invisible edges (I temporary marked them red for clarity). If you want to further adjust the position of nodes and clusters, you can play with `weight` attribute of different edges.

```
digraph G {
   rankdir=TB;
   ranksep=1;

   subgraph cluster_application {

       subgraph cluster_module_core {
         init_a -> service_a;
         init_a -> service_b;
         init_a -> service_c;
         init_a -> service_d;
       }

       subgraph cluster_module_a {
         init_d -> service_c_1;
         init_d -> service_d_1;
       }

       subgraph cluster_module_b {
         init_b -> service_a_1;
         init_b -> service_b_1;
       }

       subgraph cluster_module_db {
         init_c -> db_service;
         db_service -> db;
       }
   }

   main -> init_a;
   main -> init_b;
   main -> init_c [constraint=false]
   main -> init_d;

   service_a -> service_a_1;
   service_b -> service_b_1;
   service_c -> service_c_1;
   service_d -> service_d_1;

   service_a_1 -> db_service;
   service_b_1 -> db_service;
   service_c_1 -> db_service;
   service_d_1 -> db_service;

   service_d -> init_d [color="red"] #[style=invis]
   service_d -> init_b [color="red"] #[style=invis]
   service_d_1 -> init_c [color="red"] #[style=invis]
   service_b_1 -> init_c [color="red"] #[style=invis]
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you, thought is there a particular logic behind selecting which invisible edges to select? From the look of it it seems like the logic is to form a common path in a symmetric way and edges point from to node without changing weight of internal nodes. so init is always first.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix well there's no particular logic, what I usually do is I plot a graph without invisible edges and then start adding them to the parts which need to be adgusted. E.g. in a vertical graph I would add edge from A to B if B should appear approximately below A on the graph

Comment: Makes, sense. quite ugly thought.