# Fixing the position of clusters in graphviz

Tags: graphviz

How would I force the order of clusters in Graphviz?  For example, I have three clusters: inputs, processes, outputs.  I want to ensure that the clusters are in the diagram in that order from leaft to right, then in each cluster I don't really care which order they appear or layout used.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no easy fix to the problem of positioning clusters.  (see [How do I get individual clusters on 3 different levels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60046742/how-do-i-get-individual-clusters-on-3-different-levels/60051886#60051886))
If invisible edges don't work for your graph (sometimes they do and sometimes not), look at **gvpack** (https://graphviz.org/pdf/gvpack.1.pdf).  This program lets you create the 3 "clusters" as independent graphs and then will allow you to pack (glue) the three graphs into one graph.